# Not able to include images in HTML file on Linux EC2 instance

Tags: html, linux, amazon-ec2

[image: Accessed using ec2 instance ip address][image: Webpage when launched from local machine]I launched an Amazon EC2 instance and hosted my html page under /var/www/html/index.html and stored my images in /var/www/html/images folder but the images are not displaying in the webpage on the browser.
i have given 
Where am I supposed to keep my images?

Comment: Correction: I have given <img src='images/imagename.jpg'>

Comment: can you try adding height/width attributes as well and see if the image is being correctly populated on the webpage

Comment: Tried. Still not working. I even checked in other browsers.

Comment: The webpage is being correctly displayed if launched from my local machine, but not from the EC2 instance

Comment: The error is `You don't have permission to access /images/cardio.jpg on this server.`, so check folder permissions

Comment: I believe I have the permission to the images folder. I have uploaded a snapshot.

Comment: can you change the ownership of Cardiology.html to ec2-user:ec2-user from root:root

Comment: I changed the ownership to ec2-user:ec2-user for each of the html pages and the images. The problem is still there.

Comment: make the **src** start with **/** before images

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: Figured it was the problem in the way the jpg files were transferred. I had used WinSCP for the transfer, but when I used scp command to transfer it, the images started appearing.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who replied.